# Can a Radio button carry multiple values

Tags: html, forms

Is it possible to pass key values pairs in a radio button submit instead of a single value?

Regular Radio field:

```
<input type="radio" name="foo" value="bar" id="fooBar" required="true" checked>
```

but maybe something like:

```
<input type="radio" name="['key1', 'key2', 'key3']" value="['value1, 'value2', 'value3']" id="fooBar" required="true" checked>
```

Comment: Can you give us an example of what you're trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: There's likely a better way to do what you are asking. If you tell us your purpose behind this with a real example, we can try to help you come up with something better.

Comment: you could use a string separated by a comma or dash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not as such.

The value attribute holds a string. When you submit the form, that string will be sent to the server.

---

You could use a serialisation technique to store a more complex data structure as a string (for example: JSON) and then decode it on the server.

```
<input type="radio" name="example" value='{ "key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", "key3": "value3" }'>
```

And then something like:

```
sub process_form :Local {
    my ($self, $catalyst) = @_;
    my $radio_value = $catalyst->request->parameters->{example};
    my $decoded_radio_value = decode_json $radio_value;
    $c->log->debug("Value of key1 is " . $decoded_radio_value->{key1});
}
```

---

You could also store all the data on the server and then put some kind of identifier (which could (for example) be a hash key, or a database row id) in the value attribute.

```
<input type="radio" name="example" value='44'>
```

and then something like:

```
sub process_form :Local {
    my ($self, $catalyst) = @_;
    my $radio_value = $catalyst->request->parameters->{example};
    my $database_row = $catalyst->model("ExampleTable")->find($radio_value);
    $c->log->debug("Value of key1 is " . $database_row->key1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Html :

```
<input type="radio" name="attribut111" id="attr_id" value="2221, 9886">
```

in javascript:
First of all, get the value, then split it by a comma and make it like an arry. Then  you can use those easily.

```
var check_prod_attr = $("input:radio[name=attribut111]:checked").val();
        
var nameArr = check_prod_attr.split(',');
console.log(nameArr);
console.log(nameArr[0]);
console.log(nameArr[1]);
```